# What is the difference between Jenkin's `Replay` and `Rebuild` options?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

If you want to re-run a Jenkins job, you can click the `Rebuild` button which sometimes appears as the `Replay` button.

**What is the difference `Rebuild`ing a job versus `Replay`ing it?**

**Why is it that some jobs display `Replay` while others display `Rebuild`?**

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Rebuild, using the [Rebuilder plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/rebuild/) allows a completed job to be re-executed while allowing you to change the parameters, assuming your job is parameterized.

Replay does something similar, except it doesn't show you parameters. Instead, it shows the pipeline code directly. This is helpful when wanting to test changes iteratively as you can click Replay, change one or two lines of code, then let it execute. The job will run using the same parameters as it did the first time it ran/completed.

Comment: This only answers half the question.  Why is rebuild/retrigger not an option sometimes?

Comment: Replay won't appear if the code isn't loaded. If you abort the pipeline or have SCM authentication issues, and git can't load the code, you won't see the replay button. If you have jenkins code inline this won't be an issue.